# Override CSS style of an external widget

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress where I want to use the tree counter widget from this site: https://kb.tree-nation.com/knowledge/tree-and-co2-counters (the top one).

How do I override the CSS style of that widget? Custom CSS in Wordpress doesn't work.

I actually just need to show the number value (the count of trees).

Comment: Do you want it like this? https://nimb.ws/ChGgM1

Comment: The changes can work if you follow one of the options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe but it depends on their code enabling CORS.

Answer (score 1):

If you embedded an iframe that is hosted in another website, you will not be able to edit the style of the elements inside the iframe by adding CSS to your website.